# Share a uri with another app

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

How can I share a `Uri` from my app with another app? It may be pointing to a dropbox file, google drive file, a local `File` or a local `DocumentFile`.

My app has permissions to read the `Uri`, now I want to share it with another app and hand on the permissions. How would I do that?

Do I really have to write my own content provider?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I really have to write my own content provider?

You do not have the ability to force a third-party provider (e.g., Dropbos, Google Drive) to grant access to a separate third-party app. That would be akin to me being able to grant other people access to your bank account, just because you gave me access to your bank account.

The overall share mechanism is designed for content that you manage, or for simple stuff (e.g., plain text).

Your choices are:

1. Do not share stuff that you do not manage.
2. Make a local copy (in a file) of the content and share that, such as via a `ContentProvider`.
3. Attempt to make a proxy `ContentProvider`, one that reads in the content and serves it up directly via a pipe, rather than serving from a local file that contains a copy of the content. For `ACTION_SEND`, this may work, but bear in mind that pipe-backed streams are not seekable, and so certain types of apps, like media players, do not like pipe-backed streams.

Comment: I write a gallery app and I want the user to be able to select any image or video in my app via `android.intent.action.PICK` and `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT`. This should work with a video player as well, so you would suggest to make a local copy of the data and make this local data accessible via a content provider? Even if the data may already be local somewhere on the sd card?

Comment: @prom85: I would suggest that you limit your app to external storage, or that you limit these features to external storage. I do not believe that the user experience will be very good for what you are trying to do with content from other sources.

Comment: If I do limit this to the external storage only, how would you suggest share the uri? Direclty handing on the uri seems not to work...

Comment: @prom85: I would try to use `FileProvider` to serve up the file via a `content` `Uri`, where you add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` (and perhaps `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`) on the `Intent` you use for `setResult()`. I haven't tried implementing `ACTION_PICK` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities, so it may be that this approach is wrong, but it is where I would start.

Comment: So I wil have to use my own provider, as I just can't reuse the media store uri directly, because I can't hand on the read uri permissions? I will try that...

Comment: @prom85: It is possible that for legacy reasons, a `Uri` that you get from the `MediaStore` could be handed over to another app. I had not considered that possibility, and I am skeptical that it will work, so if that is what you tried in your "Direclty handing on the uri seems not to work" comment, I am not surprised. I had assumed that you were manually working directly with external storage (using `File`) based on your question.

Comment: Nevermind, talking about `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` lead me to the right direction. I can set this flag in the Intent I return in `Activity.setResult(...)` function, with this flag set I can share a `Uri` directly and the receiving app can read it then